# Python apply function to each row of DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have DataFrame with two columns: `Type` and `Name`. The values in each cell are lists of equal length, i.e we have pairs `(Type, Name)`. I want to:

1. Group `Name` by it's `Type`
2. Create column `Type` with the values of `Name`s

My current code is a for loop:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for t in list(set(row["Type"])):
        df.at[idx, t] = [row["Name"][i] for i in range(len(row["Name"])) if row["Type"][i] == t]
```

but it works very slow. How can I speed up this code?

**EDIT** Here is the code example which ilustrates what I want to obtain but in a faster way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Type": [["1", "1", "2", "3"], ["2","3"]], "Name": [["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["E", "F"]]})

unique = list(set(row["Type"]))
for t in unique:
    df[t] = None
    df[t] = df[t].astype('object')

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for t in unique:
        df.at[idx, t] = [row["Name"][i] for i in range(len(row["Name"])) if row["Type"][i] == t]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use the values in the cell directly instead of lists of values? Then you don't need iterrows anymore

Comment: Could you show an example of the data? Pandas doesn't work very well with lists as elements, so this is working a bit uphill - maybe you could use a different way to express this code in pandas?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish, however `pandas` doesn't like `iterrows` or similars, just try to vectorize your code.

Comment: I added more details to the quesiton

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function **my_function(param)** and then do something like this:

```
df['type'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: my_function(x))
```

There are likely better alternatives to using lambda functions, but lambdas are what I remember. If you post a simplified mock of your original data and what the desired output should look like, it may help you find the best answer to your question. I'm not certain I understand what you're trying to do. A literal group by should be done using [Dataframes' groupby method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Comment: I added details to my question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your dataframe looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a,b,c','d,e,f,g'], 'Type':['3,3,2','1,2,2,1']}) 


Name    Type
0   a,b,c   3,3,2
1   d,e,f,g 1,2,2,1
```

where the elements are lists of strings.
Start with running:

```
df['Name:Type'] = (df['Name']+":"+df['Type']).map(process)
```

using:

```
def process(x):
    x_,y_ = x.split(':')
    x_ = x_.split(','); y_ = y_.split(',')
    s = zip(x_,y_)
    str_ = ','.join(':'.join(y) for y in s)
    return str_
```

Then you will get:

[image]

This reduces the problem to a single column.
Finally produce the dataframe required by:

```
l = ','.join(df['Name:Type'].to_list()).split(',')
pd.DataFrame([i.split(':') for i in l], columns=['Name','Type'])
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: I added details to my question

Answer (score 0):

is it the result you want? (if not then add to your question an example of desired output):

```
res = df.explode(['Name','Type']).groupby('Type')['Name'].agg(list)

print(res)
'''
Type
1    [A, B]
2    [C, E]
3    [D, F]
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

**UPD**

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Name'],x['Type']).groupby(level=0).agg(list).T,1)
res = pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1)

print(res)
'''
           Type          Name       1    2    3
0  [1, 1, 2, 3]  [A, B, C, D]  [A, B]  [C]  [D]
1        [2, 3]        [E, F]     NaN  [E]  [F]
```

Comment: Not exactly, I added the desired result to my question

Comment: It works but much slower than my solution :( DataFrame has about 1mln such rows